# keras model.predict randomises the output order?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to keras and Tensorflow. I have trained a model in Keras using Tensorflow as backend, for reducing a specific noise of images. When I use this model to predict a set of test images(noisy, shape=[batchsize_1, width_1, height_1]), I have got correct predicted images(noise removed, shape=[batchsize_1, width_1, height_1]), but the order of the predicted images are randomised. As the order of the predicted images are important to my next step, how could I keep the order of predicted image identical to test images?

Here are my code for loading the model and predict the test data:

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
adam=Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
loaded_model.compile(loss=losses.mean_absolute_error, optimizer=adam)
predict_images= loaded_model.predict(test_images, batch_size=16)
```

I am sure that the `test_images` are in order in the dimension of batchsize, but the batchsize order of `predict_images` is randomised. Does the order of `predict_image` also depend on how I trained the model? How could I remain the order of `predict_image` unchanged?

Any comments and help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have the similar problem too, and I could not solve with `predict_classes`...

Comment: How do you know that the outputs are randomized? What Keras and TF versions do you have?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro As I am new to python, I saved `predict_images` as mat file and used MATLAB `permute` to change it to the dimension of [width_1, height_1, batchsize_1]. I did the same for `test_images`. Then I use `imagescn` to compare the order of `test_images` and `predict_images` visually. The `test_images` remained unchanged in order but `predict_images` has it's order changed without pattern.

Tensorflow version=1.11.0

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Tensorflow version=1.11.0, Keras=2.2.4, using in Anaconda's Jupyter

Comment: And I found the definition of `predict` here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/33902e53eb7312fbf2f17b7b700bdb7683441a24/keras/engine/training.py Does anyone know if it is randomising the output please?

Comment: Predict randomizing the output would make no sense, I haven't seen this problem and I am  a very heavy Keras user, that's why I am a bit skeptic of it. It could be a bug, but for that you need code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I agree with @MatiasValdenegro. If the order is wrong, then the error must be in your loaded model. Could you also show how you define and train it?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is a generator, you need to pass shuffle=False (by default it is True), or your predictions will be shuffled.
Example

```
imageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe, shuffle=False)
```